# How can we obtain table within a nested div using soup.find

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a div class called - 'class="table-wrap MEDdata"', within which there is another div class - 'table-container small-screen-full-width' , within this i have a table - 'course_catalog_table' which i want to access. Here is the link to the page from which I am trying to scrape-http://www.nyit.edu/academics/courses/
How can this be achieved? Please help

> Output:  table = div.find('table', {'id':'course_catalog_table'})
>   AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "lxml")

  l =[]


 div= soup.find_all('div' , {'id': 'table-wrap MEDdata'})


 table = div.find('table', {'id':'course_catalog_table'})


 for row in table.findAll("a"):
    l.append(row.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. 1) `find_all` returns a ResultSet or a list which can't be chained with another `find` method, you can just use `find` here since the element is unique; 2) the `table-wrap MEDdata` is the class attribute instead of `id`. After fixing these two issues, it should work:

```
l = []
div = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'table-wrap MEDdata'})

table = div.find('table', {'id':'course_catalog_table'})
​
for row in table.findAll("a"):
    l.append(row.text)

l
#['ACLS',
# 'Advanced Cardiac Life Support',
# 'MAOB',
# 'Ob Gyn',
# 'MAAN',
# ...
```

Comment: If u can look at this link --> http://www.nyit.edu/academics/courses/  , there is no div id... and the table id is same for each of the course data

Comment: That's why I changed the id for div to class. And the class for the three courses are different, which you can use to identify the table.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That helped..                                                             div = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'table-wrap MEDdata'})  

table = div.find('table', {'id':'course_catalog_table'})

Answer (score 0):

Psidom gave you a pretty good idea about the answer but to explain this a little bit.

```
find_all # Will give you a list of elements that you can access with an index
div= soup.find_all('div' , {'id': 'table-wrap MEDdata'}
```

This is A LIST so you can not use *`div.find`* on all the elements, you can use a loop

```
for elements in div:
    print (div.find('table', {'id':'course_catalog_table'}))
```

Or you can do for example `div = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'table-wrap MEDdata'})[0]`   where **[0]** is the index, so you can do [0] or [1] (depending on the amount of elements) and your code will work with if you use this instead.